# How to recover publicKey from signature + known message?

Tags: signature, signing, message

I'm implementing a sign in with Solana, and i'm trying to recover the user's publicKey from their signature + the known message they signed.

I know for Ethereum, ethers provides a method to do this, but I can't seem to find the equivalent on Solana.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Solana uses the [ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) signature scheme. You can use any JS lib that implements ed25519 to handle signing/verifying etc

I couldn't find one that implements a public key recovery, though according to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53226/is-it-possible-to-derive-an-ed25519-public-key-from-an-ed25519-signature) post, its mathematically possible